# how to read the json response from my response httpwebreponse

Tags: c#, .net, json, stream

This is my sample string

```
{
"aaa": "0",
"nnn": "Ok",
"rrr": [
    {
        "id": "0",
        "name": "Reserved",
        "desc": "Reserved",
        "shortdesc": "",
        "price": "07.80",
        "isvariableprice": "0",
        "taxcategoryid": "0",
        "istaxinclusive": "0",
        "brandid": "1",
        "isnetsalesexempt": "0",
        "itemtype": "0",
        "skus": [],
        "modifiergroups": [],
        "prices": [],
        "pricerules": [],
        "categories": [],
        "nutrition": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "amount": "10.0000"
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

I want to only retrieve "id" and "price" from the sample json response. The JSON is more that this and have multiple id;s and prices ... how do I put a loop to retrieve all those in an array. Please help.

This is where I am right now.

```
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    Console.WriteLine("Response stream received.");

                    string resultString = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                    //var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

                    var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(resultString));
                    dynamic data = JsonObject.Parse(resultString);

                    Console.WriteLine(data.id); //??????????

                    readStream.Close();
                }
```

this code gives me above string in "data" but I want to pull "id" and "price"

thx in advance all you gurus

Answer (score 0):

Json.Net will make your life easier when working with JSON http://json.codeplex.com/

With Json.Net in place.

You can do this in a dynamic fashion or in a strongly typed fashion.

dynamic:

```
var dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(yourJsonString);

    //for simple values
    Console.WriteLine(dynJson.aaa);
    Console.WriteLine(dynJson.nnn);

    //for list values
    foreach(var r in dynJson.rrr){
        //for simple values in rrr
        Console.WriteLine(r.id);

        //for list values in rrr
        foreach(var price in rrr.prices)
          Console.WriteLine(price)
    }
```